# Creating a DateTime column from seperate time and date columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

So I have this :

```
df=pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df

    time             date
0   21:11:07    2022-08-04
1   21:11:12    2022-08-04
2   21:11:27    2022-08-04
```

and I want to turn it into this:

```
    datetime               time       date 
0   2022-08-04 21:11:07   21:11:07   2022-08-04
1   2022-08-04 21:11:12   21:11:12   2022-08-04
2   2022-08-04 21:11:27   21:11:27   2022-08-04
```

in the **datetime64[ns]** format. I must keep the time and date columns as well.

I've tried:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('date')) + pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('time'))
```

but the other 2 columns disappear. How do I keep 'dates' and 'time' columns?

Answer (score 1):

Remove [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) which drop columns - new column is created like last column:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
#df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])
print (df)
       time        date            datetime
0  21:11:07  2022-08-04 2022-08-04 21:11:07
1  21:11:12  2022-08-04 2022-08-04 21:11:12
2  21:11:27  2022-08-04 2022-08-04 21:11:27
```

If need first column `datetime` use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df.insert(0, 'datetime', pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['time']))
#df.insert(0, 'datetime', pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time']))
print (df)
             datetime      time        date
0 2022-08-04 21:11:07  21:11:07  2022-08-04
1 2022-08-04 21:11:12  21:11:12  2022-08-04
2 2022-08-04 21:11:27  21:11:27  2022-08-04
```